# UDK - Type mismatch in 'If' for MyInventory functil

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I am having trouble getting a pawn class to compile.
The error is **Type mismatch in 'If'** in the line:
        if( MyInventory[inc] == int (x) );

CODE:
[CODE]class BSAPawn extends UTPawn;

var() array MyInventory;

function bool HasItem(int x)
{
    local int len;
    local int inc;
    len = MyInventory.Length;

```
for(inc = 0; inc < len; inc++)
{
   if( MyInventory[inc] = int x );
        return true;
}
return false;
```

}[/CODE]

Does anyone know how to sort this out?
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a value `=` instead of doing a comparison `==`

it should look like..

```
for(inc = 0; inc < len; inc++)
{
   if( MyInventory[inc] == x )
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Plus why are you using `int x` instead of simply `x`